# Javascript - Display array elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a simple Javascript to display the elements of an array that I create by splitting a string. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Loops</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var text = "01/01/2016";
  var parts = text.split("/");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var x += parts[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code does not display anything on the browser and I can't for the life of me figure out where the error is. Can someone advise?

Comment: You should check the developer console for errors

Comment: @Craicerjack var declaration is not block scoped, so this isn't true.

Comment: @AndréWerlang you are right of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is tricky, so any JavaScript compiler would complaint:

```
var x += parts[i] + "<br>";
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +=

You can't declare a variable with the "+=" assignment operator.

Let's rewrite this assignment:

```
var x = x + parts[i] + "<br>";
```

When it works, the result is the same. Only that the first time this runs, `x` is undefined, not initialized yet. Concatenating `undefined` to any a string will contain the string *undefined* in the result.

But does it re-declare the variable? No, because a concept called hoisting, any variable declaration, even inside a loop, is pushed to the top of the scope, in this case the global scope. (We're not talking about `let` and `const`)

To solve that, before you read from this variable, you need to definitely assign to it, i.e. initialize.

```
var x = '';
```

Later you'll be able to use the operator `+=`, and then you don't need to use the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

fgil give you good answer - you declare x variable in loop, at the first - it's not initialized (you have get error on += ), and second - you reset variable each iteration by declaring it at the loop. But I think that this loop is not needed. You can make code more simple and short if you will use method join of Array. Look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Loops</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var text = "01/01/2016";
  var parts = text.split("/");
  var x = parts.join("<br>") + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here fiddler with sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bofr17tp/)

You can do it in one line:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "01/01/2016".split("/").join("<br>") + "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just failing in a basic concept. *var x* must be declared before the loop, like this:

```
var x = '';
for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    x += parts[i] + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: there's a basic concept you're failing, called hoisting

Comment: Except that fgil is correct for this particular use. The declaration of a variable may be hoisted, but the initial assignment is not hoisted. And I don't even know where to begin with using += with a variable declaration. I think if it worked at all it would be undefined01<br>.....

Answer (score 0):

Define x outside the for loop.

```
var text = "01/01/2016";
var parts = text.split("/");
var x = "";
for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) { 
    x = x + parts[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```